# Find an efficient method for a convex optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Consider the linear minimization problem over an ellipsoid and the nonnegative orthant as:
$$\min \{a' x : x'Bx\leq 1, x\geq 0 \}$$
where the coefficients $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric positive definite. Obviously, this problem is a convex optimization problem with a convex quadratic constraint. Hence many quadratic programming solvers can handle this problem such as GUROBI, CPLEX and MOSEK. However, this problem is so special that I think there should exist some elegant methods to solve it either directly or numerically with a fast convergence rate without invoking external optimization solvers. Hoping to get some ideas. All comments and suggestions are welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One can use operator or proximal splitting methods for such a problem -- I think (without thinking too much...). If one follows this path, then it may seem enticing. However, If $B$ has rank more than 1, then I suspect "computationally efficient" solution because one might have to resort to SVD to compute to orthogonal projection onto such an ellipsoid.

Comment: @user550103 thanks for your suggestion. Sure, operator splitting methods are obviously applicable to this problem. But I pretty much expect a more elegant approach. Here $B$ is a full-rank matrix and invertible, whose eigenvalue decomposition could be expensive for large-scale cases. However, if such a decomposition leads to a closed-form solution to this problem, I will be very glad to try it.